# Using requests.post to submit a form

Tags: python, asp.net, python-requests

Building a webscraper to query the USGA golf course database for a list of all courses and ratings. A form submission generates a table of links to different courses, which can then be scraped for the data I'm curious about.

How do I use requests.post to submit all possible queries into the form. Currently, I have:

```
import csv
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from requests import Session
import requests


url = "https://ncrdb.usga.org/NCRDB/NCRListing.aspx"
data = {'txtClubCity': r"Newton"}
r = requests.post(url, data=data)

print r.content
```

I've tried this a bunch of different ways, but the page doesn't update after posting. Does anyone have a sense of what's wrong here?

Comment: you are missing the club name and the club state